# Can I use computed properties within component's slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, slot, computed-properties

Recently I found out that I can't use computed property or a data properties within the components slot. Even though computed is defined in the component, I am not able to use it in the component's slot. Is there any way of getting it work?

Example code:

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
   template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
   computed: {
      my_computed: function(){
         return 2+3; // not defined in slot
      }
    }
})
<div id="app">
     <test-component>
        <span v-text="my_computed"></span>
     </test-component>
</div>
```

See live example here,
https://jsfiddle.net/gu9jh4n0/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [Scoped Slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) to achieve that.

In your example, your component will look like this :

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
  template: '<div><slot :computed="my_computed"></slot></div>',
  computed: {
    my_computed: function(){
        return 2+3; // not defined in slot
    }
  }
});
```

And the main template will retrieve the slot's scope and use the computed :

```
<test-component>
  <span slot-scope="data" v-text="data.computed"></span>
</test-component>
```

[Live example.](https://jsfiddle.net/gu9jh4n0/2/)